# Line Art Effect by Pixel Shader in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, pixel, shader

I want to create a Line Art effect but as I got vertex shader is not supported by WPF now. Is there a way to create Line Art effect by Pixel Shader? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Shader Effect Library](http://www.codeplex.com/wpffx), you will most likely have to create your own Pixel Shader to obtain the effect you want, but there is a good tutorial that can teach you how on that site as well.